# Form will show up or not, depending on HOW I call it

Tags: c#

I'm working on an app that analyzes UDP network packets, but I got stuck in a weird situation.

I have a form (Form6 from here) with this events:

```
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }

private void Form6_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //STUFF...
        }
```

Then, on another class, I have to create an instance of Form6.

If I do it like this, the Form6 instance shows up, but I rely on a timer (not exactly a good way to do what I need, but it "works"):

```
public void newpacket(Packet p_packet)
        {
            //STUFF...
            newnotif = true;
        }

private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (newnotif == true)
            {
                newnotif = false;
                Form6 f6 = new Form6();
                f6.notifname = namenotifconnect;
                if (Class1.notifpos)
                    Class1.notifpos = false;
                else
                    Class1.notifpos = true;
                f6.Show();
                f6.timer1.Enabled = true;
                f6.temp = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
```

But, If I do it like this for example (calling a method), the form won't show up (but I know it's created, because I can see the icon with the Form6 name in the taskbar)

```
public void newpacket(Packet p_packet)
        {
            //STUFF...
            notif(1, namenotifconnect);
        }

public void notif(int type,string name)
        {
            if(type == 1) //SHOW
            {
                    Form6 f6 = new Form6();
                    f6.notifname = name;
                    if (Class1.notifpos)
                        Class1.notifpos = false;
                    else
                        Class1.notifpos = true;
                    f6.Show();
                    f6.timer1.Enabled = true;
                    f6.temp = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
```

Another way it works, is if I do the 'create instance code' in a buttonclick event, but that's not what I want, since it must be automatic, when I receive a packet.

Not sure why is happening this, why would work with a timer, and not with 'notif' method.

Hope someone can give me a clue of what's happening here.

Comment: Does 'newpacket' happen to be getting called by another thread?

Comment: Actually, it just appears in an argument of another method on another thread:

`recPaquetsThread = new Thread(recPaquets);
recPaquetsThread.Start();
private void recPaquets()
        {
            communicator.ReceivePackets(0, newpacket);
        }`

Comment: There's your problem, UI components should only ever be created/accessed and modified from the UI thread, you can do this by delegating your form creation code *onto* the UI thread from your 'recPaquetsThread' using [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: First, what kind of timer is it (System.Timers.Timer or System.Windows.Forms.Timer or System.Threading.Timer ?). Second, does it work if you use ShowDialog instead of Show? (this should make that thread the marshaling thread for the new form)

Comment: @M.A.Hanin you shouldn't call ShowDialog on a background thread either...

Comment: @James

Never used Invoke, but found a nice post, and I managed to get it to work like a charm:

`this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            notif(1, name);
                        });`

Thanks a lot mate.

@M.A.Hanin

The solution you provided works partially for me, it shows the object, but gets stuck.

Comment: @Vitrus I wasn't in front of a machine last night but I will post an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I see you are trying to create the form on a background thread, that's more than likely the reason you are seeing this unexpected behaviour.

UI components should only ever be created/accessed and modified on the UI thread. You can marshall your UI specific code onto the UI thread by using [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) / [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void newpacket(Packet p_packet)
{
    //STUFF...
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
        notif(1, namenotifconnect); 
    });
}
```